# Creating a wizard using ui:include, rich:popupPanel and navigation-rules

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, faces-config, uiinclude

I am trying to build a wizard using ui:include in a RichFaces 4 popupPanel and navigation-rules in the faces-config.xml, but on completing the actions in the backing bean, the page does not navigate to the target page. I have checked to ensure that the bean executes as expected and that it provides the expected outcome.

The JSF page and the included page are listed below:

```
<rich:popupPanel modal="true" id="addSvcAcctPanel" autosized="true">

        <rich:messages id="addSvcAcctPanelMessages" globalOnly="false"
            styleClass="message" />

        <a:outputPanel id="includeAddSvcAcct">          
            <ui:include src="/layout/addSvcAccPg2.xhtml" />
        </a:outputPanel>                    

        <h:form id="closeSvcAcctForm">
            <div class="buttons">
                <a:commandButton styleClass="save" id="closeAddSvcBtn"
                    value="close"
                    onclick="#{rich:component('addSvcAcctPanel')}.hide()"
                    render="hasAgentsAccItm,svcAccAccordItm,svcAcctsTab,svcAccInfo,agentPanel,ServiceAccts,noticesAccordion">
                    <rich:tooltip direction="topRight" mode="client" showDelay="300"
                        styleClass="tooltip" layout="block">

                        <span style="white-space: wrap">Click on the 'Close'
                            button to close this panel and return to the main screen. If you
                            have any unsaved information on this page, it will be lost when
                            you click close.</span>

                    </rich:tooltip>
                </a:commandButton>
            </div>              
        </h:form>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

The inserted JSF code for the two panels is as follows:

Pg 1.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<h:form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:richext="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/richext"
    xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

    <rich:panel id="addSvcAcctPanelContent" headerClass="head2" style="height:100%;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText styleClass="med_black_type_bold_facet"
                value="Add a Service Account" />
        </f:facet>



        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText styleClass="med_black_type_bold"
                value="Department" id="companyLabel" />

            <rich:select styleClass="med_black_type" id="companySelect"
                required="true" value="#{main.selected_company}" render="acctWarning, accountLabel1" valueChangeListener="#{main.determineProperAccountName}">
                <f:selectItem
                    itemLabel="Please select an Organisation"
                    itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{country_companies}" />
                <a:ajax event="selectitem" render="acctWarning, accountLabel1, acctNumberExplain, acctIdHeader, acctIDHelp" execute="@this"/>               
            </rich:select>

            <rich:message for="companySelect" style=" width : 330px;" />

            <h:outputText styleClass="med_black_type_bold"
                value="Account 'Nickname'" id="nicknameLabel" />


            <h:inputText styleClass="med_black_type" id="nickname"
                value="#{main.alias}" onfocus="#{rich:component('nickNameHelpPanel')}.show()"
                onblur="#{rich:component('nickNameHelpPanel')}.hide()">
                <rich:validator />  

                <!-- <f:ajax event="focus" execute="@this" onevent="#{rich:component('nickNameHelpPanel')}.show()"/>        
                <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this" onevent="#{rich:component('nickNameHelpPanel')}.hide()"/> --> 
            </h:inputText>
            <rich:message for="nickname" style=" width : 330px;" />

            <richext:spacer width="30" />
            <h:outputText id="acctWarning" styleClass="med_blue_type_bold"
                value="Enter the #{main.accountProperName} below - numbers and letters only! No dots or dashes." />
            <richext:spacer width="30" />

            <h:outputText styleClass="med_black_type_bold"
                value="#{main.accountProperName}" id="accountLabel1" />

            <h:inputText styleClass="med_black_type" id="account"
                value="#{main.account_id}" onfocus="#{rich:component('acctIDHelpPanel')}.show()"
                onblur="#{rich:component('acctIDHelpPanel')}.hide()">
                <rich:validator />

                <!-- <f:ajax event="focus" execute="@this" onevent="#{rich:component('acctIDHelpPanel')}.show()"/>      
                <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this" onevent="#{rich:component('acctIDHelpPanel')}.hide()"/> --> 
            </h:inputText>
            <rich:message for="account" style=" width : 330px;" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <div class="buttons">

            <a:commandButton styleClass="save" id="addServiceCompany"
                value="save" action="#{main.addAccount}" render="includeAddSvcAcct, includeAddSvcAcct1"/>
        </div>
    </rich:panel>



</h:form>
```

Pg 2.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<h:form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:richext="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/richext"
    xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<rich:panel>
    <h:outputText value="The service account has been successfully added." styleClass="med_black_type"/>
</rich:panel>
```

The relevant excerpt from the faces-config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.1" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">

 <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/layout/addSvcAccPg2.seam</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-action>#{main.outcome}</from-action>
   <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/layout/addSvcAccPg3.seam</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>

 <application>
  <locale-config>
   <default-locale>en</default-locale>
   <supported-locale>bg</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>tr</supported-locale>
  </locale-config>
 </application>
</faces-config>
```

The method from the backing bean is as follows:

```
public String addAccount() {
        String retVal = "failed";
        try {

            getSAFctx.addService(getIntUserId(), 1, selected_company,
                    account_id, alias);         
            retVal = "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {

           System.out.println(e.getMessage());                  

        } finally {                     

            return retVal;
        }
}
```

I have tried to this using pages.xml, *.pages.xml and rich:togglePanel (which for some reason, does not permit commandButtons to engage backing beans). Does anyone have any suggestions that can help? Does anyone know how to make this wizard work?

Thanks in advance.

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code it is clear that once the page /layout/addSvcAccPg2.seam is included inside the rich:popupPanel , then it will lead to situation having same ID's for two different components's in a single page .

You have used ID="addSvcAcctPanel" for rich:popupPanel and rich:panel. This is a common issue with richfaces and creates page navigation problems .

Just make them different and try once again .

Comment: Hi Kshitij, Sorry about that. Power went out as I was typing the reply. In looking at it, I am surprised that an error was not thrown when it tried to render the page. That being said, when the command button calls the backing bean, the method is executed as expected, but the popup's contents still do not change.

Comment: you have written  action="#{main.addAccount}" inside the command button . But in the faces-config.xml you are using <from-action>#{main.outcome}</from-action> . From where this outcome variable is populated ???

Can you suggest that how this outcome variable is being populated from the above pasted code ?

Comment: What is currently there is from my messing around with various scenarios, trying to make it work. The variable {main.outcome}, in the current version is populated by the same addAccount() method. Before, the navigation rules were based on the outcome of the addAccount() method, but that did not work. THinking that it had to do with the availability of the result of the method, I added a class variable to the SFSB that houses the method and populated it with the value of the outcome. The variable name is outcome, but the line was <from-action>#{main.addAccount}</from-action> before.